# Android BroadcastReceiver Thread/Timer as static instance variable

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The android developer site states that a BroadcastReceiver process is eligible to be removed after the onReceive() method returns and that you should not start threads/timers within the BroadcastReceiver. But how does this relate to static instance variables of the Thread/Timer class? I assume that these static instance variables still exists because they are bound to the loaded class? Or am I wrong (e.g. because the process is started within a new dalvik JVM) and should I never use threads/timers within BroadcastReceivers?

Answer (score 1):

> Or am I wrong (e.g. because the process is started within a new dalvik JVM) and should I never use threads/timers within BroadcastReceivers?

If the `BroadcastReceiver` is registered in the manifest, do not fork threads, start timers, register listeners, or otherwise do anything tied to that receiver that would need to live beyond the receiver. If there is nothing else in your app running, your process is eligible for termination at any time, taking your stuff with you.

If the `BroadcastReceiver` is registered via `registerReceiver()` from some other component, that other component can fork threads, start timers, register listeners, or whatever else, subject to the normal rules of that component.

Comment: What happens if there is anything else running within my app (e.g. AppWidgetProvider). In that case is the process eligible for termination? Or will the static instance variable still exist and will the threads/timers work?

Comment: @Erwin: An `AppWidgetProvider` runs for a few milliseconds and goes away -- it is a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`. "In that case is the process eligible for termination?" -- absolutely. It takes an activity or service to have a shot at keeping the service alive. "Or will the static instance variable still exist and will the threads/timers work?" -- please do not use threads/timers from a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`.